# Is Powerlevel10k's Transient Prompt supposed to stay at the bottom of the window?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

If you look at [this gif](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k-media/master/transient-prompt.gif) attached to [this thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/dsh1g3/new_powerlevel10k_feature_transient_prompt/) it looks like the transient prompt is fixed to the bottom of the Terminal window. Is is supposed to do that? If so, how do you set that up? I'm using transient prompt but its behavior is the same as default (starting at the top, terminal feedback pushes the prompt down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a feature of P10k. Just put this in your `.zshrc` file, before initializing the prompt:

```sh
print ${(pl:$LINES::\n:):-}
```